# editing .oni file

Tags: kinect, openni

i've done a recording with openNI and i've getted a [.oni file](http://openni.org/docs2/ProgrammerGuide.html). in this i have rgb and depth data and solso skelton joints coordinates. this is pretty cool.
i've used the class:

```
xn::Recorder [in c++ api][2]
```

but now i need to edit this file, nothing special but basic operation like:

- cut some part at the beginning and in the end
- make it 2x faster
- take a single frame with all metadata

some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use the z-vector beta...
and if you like it, you can always buy it- it's a bit pricey, but well worth it.

The beta is free, you just import your .oni file, then hold down command and click where you want the video to start, then hold down alt and click where you want the video to end.

We use it to edit all of our oni files for our show.
Hope that helps!

-Mino

le-mino.com